# Handling "Save/Close Event" for OpenOffice.org

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, openoffice.org, uno

Few month ago I developed functionality for my Application that can handle save and close events for Microsoft Excel and Word in Delphi. I used COM.
 Now I must create the same for OpenOffice. But after a few hours of searching I didn't find any useful information. I don't know where to start. I will be very happy for any help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you tried the [OpenOffice.org for Developers](http://www.openoffice.org/development/) site?

Comment: another link for you http://www.openoffice.org/udk/common/man/tutorial/office_automation.html

Comment: Thanks. I found very interesting forum but it is on russian. There is [link](http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualthread.aspx?bid=20&tid=405083&pg=1). There are a lot of different examples and guys developed some library that helps automate interaction with OpenOffice. You can download it from [here](http://yuri.elmeh.ru/)

Answer (score 1):

UNO is the OpenOffice/LibreOffice component model.

Here is the UNO reference: http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/java/ref/overview-summary.html

Here is the Delphi/UNO bridge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/uno-pas-bridge/

With UNO you will be working with many interfaces, in a strongly typed language you will see many casts. These casts deprive the developer of IDE support which is a nuisance.